How to configure K8s in Docker Desktop to proxy image pulls via Artifactory
I'm working with an organization which has a policy that all Docker images from public repositories like Docker Hub must be proxied through its private Artifactory mirror service.  When using Docker commands directly or writing a Dockerfile, this is fairly straightforward by prefixing all image references with their Artifactory mirror path, e.g.: docker pull mirror.company.com/image.  However, I'm trying to test a vendor product using the Kubernetes feature of Docker Desktop, and the installation instructions consist solely of using Helm with the vendor's chart (from their chart repo).  This is failing to work, I believe, because the images references in the chart don't include the Artifactory mirror prefix:
% kubectl -n kong-system get pods                                                    
NAME                                                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
kgo-gateway-operator-controller-manager-7b84447bb6-wnw7v   0/2     ImagePullBackOff   0          22m
 % kubectl -n kong-system describe pods kgo-gateway-operator-controller-manager-7b84447bb6-wnw7v
Name:             kgo-gateway-operator-controller-manager-7b84447bb6-wnw7v
Namespace:        kong-system
...
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  23m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned kong-system/kgo-gateway-operator-controller-manager-7b84447bb6-wnw7v to docker-desktop
  Warning  Failed     23m (x2 over 23m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     23m (x2 over 23m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    23m (x2 over 23m)     kubelet            Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/kubebuilder/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.8.0"
  Warning  Failed     23m (x2 over 23m)     kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    22m (x3 over 23m)     kubelet            Pulling image "docker.io/kong/gateway-operator:1.2"
  Warning  Failed     22m (x3 over 23m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "docker.io/kong/gateway-operator:1.2": Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Access to registry-1.docker.io has been restricted by your administrators. To access this registry, ask your administrators to add it to your organization's allowed registries.
  Warning  Failed     22m (x3 over 23m)     kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   Pulling    22m (x3 over 23m)     kubelet            Pulling image "gcr.io/kubebuilder/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.8.0"
  Warning  Failed     22m (x3 over 23m)     kubelet            Failed to pull image "gcr.io/kubebuilder/kube-rbac-proxy:v0.8.0": Error response from daemon: Get "https://gcr.io/v2/": Access to gcr.io has been restricted by your administrators. To access this registry, ask your administrators to add it to your organization's allowed registries.
  Normal   BackOff    3m23s (x89 over 23m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "docker.io/kong/gateway-operator:1.2"

Is there any setting in Docker Desktop or elsewhere to define the Artifactory mirror as some sort of default image proxy, which would allow the vendor's Helm chart to work as-is?

Don't close this question: software tools commonly used by programmers are on topic.
